# tf-idf keep feature matrix shape when transforming test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am using `tf-idf(text frequency-inverse document frequency)` to convert my text input into feature matrix..let suppose take a five sentences with each 10 different words.
So i used `input_data(5,50)`.
When to predict the model of sentence with 10 words,my feature matrix will be of size (1,10) right.So model throwing `ValueError--Cannot feed value of shape.`
Which way or method should i implement to get rid of this error..

Answer (score 1):

This is handled by the [`TfidfVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). Not sure what you're doing wrong (since there's no code), but by fitting on a set of strings (sentences) and transforming on unseen data, words that have not been seen by the transformer are ignored. Here's an example:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

l = ['Some test string', 'just another string']
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
t = tfidf.fit(l)

t.transform(l).todense()
matrix([[0.        , 0.        , 0.6316672 , 0.44943642, 0.6316672 ],
        [0.6316672 , 0.6316672 , 0.        , 0.44943642, 0.        ]])

tfidf.transform(['String with unseen words']).todense()
matrix([[0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```